# Like Confirm not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, confirmation

I'm adding a Like button to a website and currently making a few tests. At first, everything was working fine, until the Confirm link started to show up whenever I clicked the Like button. I searched this and found out it is a spam control. So I understand the button showing up, since I am liking and unliking the site many times, for test purposes, and I'm OK with that.
The problem is that, even when I click Confirm and click Like again in the popup, the Like is ignored. The counter does not show any likes and the action is not posted to the Facebook wall.
The Facebook debugger does not show anything wrong with the url either.

Here's how to reproduce:
1. Access http://sjc.prima.net.br:8777/fb_test/like_test.htm
2. Click Like button
3. Click Confirm
4. Click Like again, in the popup

See that the Like is ignored.

Any help, please?!?